# Azure Application gateway cannot upload pfx certificate

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-application-gateway

For Application gateway all documentation says to upload pfx certificate but when I go to http settings for backend pool it only allows ".cer" certificate and it wont allow ".pfx" file to be uploaded, error displayed says wrong format ? 
m i doing something wrong or somehow Azure has changed functionality but documentation is still not uploaded . 
Strangely through this command I am able to upload PFX

```
az network application-gateway ssl-cert create
```

Screenshot attached

[image]

Update : I am trying to do this for an existing Application Gateway
Update 2 : Strangely when I am creating a gateway Azure shows me option for PFX but I dont know why it become cer if I am trying to do this for an existing one.

Is this one of Microsoft's easter eggs??

Comment: i'm pretty sure it was pfx, maybe theres some dropdown to pick which certificate type to upload?

Comment: help me with this ?? as till now I am pretty sure that I have lost half of my hairs.

Comment: no idea, i've just checked on my app gateway, says upload pfx and allows to input password

Comment: humm let me try this with a windows VM it looks like that on windows it gives pfx and on linux it giver cer. Just a hunch

Comment: @BlindSniper You select a wrong entrance on Portal.  https://imgur.com/a/c2xwZ

Comment: @BlindSniper Do you see this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/c2xwZ ? My guess is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you select wrong entrance on Portal.

If you configure `Add HTTP setting`, you really need a `.cer` certificate.

[image]

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal).

The command `az network application-gateway ssl-cert create` is used for configure SSL. You could find it on Portal `Settings--Listener`.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain one more thing does this pfx certificate has any relation with cer certificate we upload in http settings

Comment: @BlindSniper Based on my understanding, pfx certificate contains private key(cer file) and public key.

Comment: For `HTTP Settings`, it works for probe to check your web app service status, it only needs a private key no need public key. So, you only need upload a .cer file.

Comment: so just to confirm if I have a cert1.cer for a vm i need to upload it for http settings and also I need to convert that too pfx using its private key and upload that pfx file too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need http setting for probe for checking web status.

Comment: If you have a pfx file and know the  passphrase(.crt), you could export the private key(.cert).

Comment: I have a linux vm with which I am provided a cer file. so I uploaded tht cer file in http settings but when creating pfx it asked for private key which i didnt have.so I am in a fix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163304/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-blindsniper).